# How to change className using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Code**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var refButton = document.getElementById("old");
  refButton.onmouseover = function() {
    refButton.className = 'newClass';
  }
};
```

```css
.newClass {
  color: white;
}
#old {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="old">
  Hello
</div>
```

If instead of `ClassName` I type `style.color="red"` then the code works.

I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: It's working, your class is applied. However, the color from the `#old` rule is overwriting the color, hence it stays blue.

Comment: [**CSS Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? looks like a very valid question

Comment: it's elementary, that's why - need to learn selector precedence.

Answer (score 6):

It is because of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), so just add `#old` to your `.newClass`

- `.newClass` has a specificity of : `0 0 1 0`
- `#old` has a specificity of : `0 1 0 0`

therefore `#old` is more specific.

using `#old.newClass` you get `0 1 1 0` which is going to be more specific and will apply the new style you want.

You can calculate the CSS specificity [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var refButton = document.getElementById("old");
  refButton.onmouseover = function() {
    refButton.className = 'newClass';
  }
};
```

```css
#old.newClass {
  color: red;
  /* changed for demo */
}
#old {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="old">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: ThankYou. Is there anything else I should take care of? Stuff like this is not generally taught in tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

if you're try to have a mouse hover effect, you can do it by replacing 'newClass' with

```
#old:hover{color:white;}
```

[jsfiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/dga79fgo/)

and just like adeneo's comment link said,

```
#old{color:blue;} //id selector
```

has higher priority than

```
.newClass{color:white;} //class selector
```

That's why the assignment doesn't work